# AngularJS - ui-date clear value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS ui-date. The below is the `html` & `js` code :-

```
<input id="dob" name="dob" ui-date="dateOptions" class="form-control" ui-date-format="dd-MM-yy" ng-model="user.dob" ng-required="true" readonly>

$scope.dateOptions = {
        startingDay: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "clip",
        clearBtn: true
    };
```

As this Datepicker is not editable, How can the i clear the value once the user selects dob?

I tried `clearBtn` but didn't worked.

Comment: `document.test.dob.value="";` where `test` will be your form name

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ui-date before, but this should work. Add a bind and a change event. Then clear your bound variable.

```
<input id="dob" name="dob" ng-change="selectChoice()" ui-date="dateOptions" class="form-control" ui-date-format="dd-MM-yy" ng-model="user.dob" data-ng-bind="user.dob" ng-required="true" readonly>

$scope.user.dob = '';//you can set the date on start using this

$scope.dateOptions = {
        startingDay: 1,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showAnim: "clip",
        clearBtn: true
    };

$scope.selectChoice = {
        alert($scope.user.dob);
//ok now clear it
$scope.user.dob = '';
    };
```